# HTML5 video "autoplay" not automatically starting in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have the following code:

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="video/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/myVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="video/myVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

The video:

1. displays well in both Chrome and Firefox
2. In Firefox it plays as expected
3. In Chrome it displays but doesn't "autostart". This is the problem.
4. If I click on it (in Chrome) it plays ok

Tried

```
<video controls autoplay>...</video>
<video controls autoplay="1">...</video>
<video controls autoplay="autoplay">...</video>
```

Nothing worked in Chrome.

Then I also tried changing the codec, as recommended in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video, but it also did not work:

```
<source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'>
<source src="movie.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>
```

Now I am at a dead end. Thanks for any pointers! Much appreciated.

Comment: A little hack (add after `</video>`): `<script> document.getElementById('myvideo').play(); 
</script>` (don't forget to add `id="myvideo"` to  `<video>`)

Comment: True, did not think about js. The little hack worked. Thanks!

Comment: @SasinduMendis it appears this will only work after user interaction with the page (e.g. click). Any sooner and `play()` will be blocked by Chrome with a message in the console.

Comment: If you want to use the `autoplay` attribute the video must have: a **longer duration of 7 seconds**, **audio must be enabled**, the **tab must be active** and the video must have a **minimum size of 200x140px**

Comment: @gmarsi any reference?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You need to add `playsinline autoplay muted loop` because Chrome does not allow a video to autostart if it is not muted. Also, right now I don't know why it is not working in all Android devices. I'm trying to look if it's version specific, if I find something I'll let you know.

Chrome issue:
After some research I have found that it doesn't work on Chrome sometimes because in responsive you can activate the data saver, and it blocks any video to autostart.

Comment: Thank you for the info about the Data Saver, this was my issue. Have you found a way to overcome this? That is, if the data saver is still on, can the video autoplay somehow, maybe via JS?

Comment: Sorry, i could not find anything to fix it

Comment: Why does chrome allow autostart on youtube? Is there an exception for youtube?

Comment: @Max, chrome doesn't allow embedded youtube videos to autoplay.

Comment: @AlexanderKim I'm not talking about embedded videos. I was refering to youtube itself. When I open a youtube video there is autoplay. Maybe there is an exception for youtube?

Comment: Just muted my video and Autopaly is working in chrome.. After reading your comment and I got it fixes..   Thank you very much @sebassierra

Answer (score 12):

Try this when i tried giving muted , check this demo in  [codpen](https://codepen.io/mmdileepthomas/pen/QroQZp)

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay muted id="videoId">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

script

```
function toggleMute() {

  var video=document.getElementById("videoId");

  if(video.muted){
    video.muted = false;
  } else {
    debugger;
    video.muted = true;
    video.play()
  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(toggleMute,3000);
})
```

edited attribute content

```
autoplay muted playsinline
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Unmuting on timeout won't work anymore, you'll get an error: Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before

Comment: If the muted video is inserted dynamically into the DOM it doesn't autoplay for me in chrome after the page refresh because of "DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first". However, in such scenario you need to set the muted attribute to true manually after element insertion as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51189390/320761

Comment: After unmute, the video stops again. it's not correct

Answer (score 7):

This may not have been the case at the time the question was asked, but as of Chrome 66, **autoplay is blocked**.

http://bgr.com/2018/04/18/google-chrome-66-download-auto-playing-videos-block/

Answer (score 6):

I was just reading [this](http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) article, and it says:

> Important: the order of the video files is vital; Chrome currently has a bug in which it will not autoplay a .webm video if it comes after anything else.

So it looks like your problem would be solved if you put the .webm first in your list of sources. Hope that helps.

Comment: You completely saved my day with this.  I can confirm this worked in Chrome 72

Comment: Chrome 74, order doesn't matter.

Comment: Chrome 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64) here and my webm is first inline. Commenting out the other `<source>`s made the webm fire. #strangebehavior

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<video src="{{ asset('path/to/your_video.mp4' )}}" muted autoplay loop playsinline></video>
```

And put this `js` after that:

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  let video = document.querySelector('video[muted][autoplay]');
  try {
    await video.play();
  } catch (err) {
    video.controls = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

These are the attributes I used to get video to autoplay on Chrome - `onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"`, `playsinline`, `autoplay`, `muted`, `loop`

Example:

```
<video src="path/to/video.mp4" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" playsinline autoplay muted loop></video>
```

Answer (score 3):

This question are greatly described here
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

TL;DR You are still always able to autoplay `muted` videos

Also, if you're want to autoplay videos on iOS add `playsInline` attribute, because by default iOS tries to fullscreen videos
https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 2):

Extremeandy has mentioned as of Chrome 66 autoplay video has been disabled.

After looking into this I found that muted videos are still able to be autoplayed. In my case the video didn't have any audio, but adding muted to the video tag has fixed it:

Hopefully this will help others also.

Answer (score -1):

Here is it: http://www.htmlcssvqs.com/8ed/examples/chapter-17/webm-video-with-autoplay-loop.html
You have to add the tags: autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" or just "autoplay" and "loop".