# HTML Video Script Stuck

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have noticed that video scripts have stopped working on chrome, but work fine on mozilla firefox, and i am wondering if there is any fix for this, i use this video script:

```
<video autoplay loop>
        <source src="lust.mp4#t=33" type="video/mp4" />
        <script>
            var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
            video.volume = 0.8; 
        </script>
        </video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML 5 Video "autoplay" not automatically starting in CHROME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764876/html-5-video-autoplay-not-automatically-starting-in-chrome)