# How does Youtube autoplay its videos?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video, autoplay

With recent changes in html5 video, it's no longer possible to autplay videos ([HTML 5 Video "autoplay" not automatically starting in CHROME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764876/html-5-video-autoplay-not-automatically-starting-in-chrome))

However, with youtube api you can still embed one of their videos with autoplay parameter and it actually does autoplay it.

How is this possible? This double standard that Google team is doing with their Chrome

Comment: Google Autoplay Policy and implementation here : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: @Shim-Sao No, this does not explain how does my website, that user has not interacted with previously, *does not* play my embedded videos but *does* autoplay videos that are loaded with youtube javascript api and embedded via an iframe - even without an interaction: `Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound`. This would mean that a user has to interact with *my* domain, not *youtube* domain previously

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Chrome autoplays Youtube videos through a whitelist.

For clean installs of Chrome, Google will include a whitelist of 1000 sites where autoplay is enabled. The sites whitelisted are based on sites where Google sees the `highest percentage of visitors play[ing] media with sound`. As you browse, the whitelist will grow to match your browsing history.

More info can be found here: [Improving Autoplay in Chrome](https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/)

> If you don’t have browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound. As you browse the web, that list changes as Chrome learns and enables autoplay on sites where you play media with sound during most of your visits, and disables it on sites where you don’t.

Comment: so if i upload any content to youtube and then autoplay it on my own custom domain with potentially annoying content/ in an abusive way it's ok? :D wow, that makes the whole point of not autoplaying videos with sound really pointless.

what a terrible idea, google

Comment: It does help though. Many of those annoying videos are ads and are prevented.

Comment: This is what i though, Google give theme self a competitive advantage over their competitors.

Comment: @VB_Dojnaz currently, youtube basically is only ads, with occasional timeframe of actual videos