# How to auto play video in html5

Tags: jquery, html

my inedx.html is started by playing full-screen video, when the video ends the button will appear on the screen by clicking the button it will redirect to another page, but my problem is when I use "autoplay muted" property audio is muted i want to play video along with audio how to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the div
  $(".btn").hide();
  // Show the div after 5s
  $(".btn").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});

function ak() {
  window.location.href = "indexpree.html";
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outerConatiner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 90px;
  top: 800px;
  left: 680px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="outerConatiner">
    <video autoplay muted>
                    <source src="./Intro.webm" type="video/webm">
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                    </video>

    <img class="btn" src="./Enter Button.png" onclick="ak()">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why you are using the `muted` property ?

Comment: if i remove this then its not working .

Comment: so check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML 5 Video "autoplay" not automatically starting in CHROME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764876/html-5-video-autoplay-not-automatically-starting-in-chrome)

Comment: can some one help me with this code ..

Answer (score 1):

As per the google's updated autoplay polices back in 2018

**Autoplay with sound is allowed only if** :

- User has interacted with the page (click, tap, etc.)
- On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning     the user has previously play video with sound.
- On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].